# (The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.) laravel solution?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I'm new to laravel and I want to submit a registration user form that when clicked, data will be sent to my database (which is already configured) and the page will be directed to the login page but when I click submit button laravel, it says

**"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."**

I've searched a lot but i am clueless as i don't understand what to do.

My registration view

```
<?php
// Include config file

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: /");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="/">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

My Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/','LoginController@login');

Route::get('registration','LoginController@registration');

Route::get('welcome','LoginController@welcome');
```

My Controller (Not sure if this could be the source of the problem but....)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function registration()
    {
        return view('registration');
    }

    public function welcome()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }


}
```

And last but not least my login file which i don't think is necessary but I'll just share as well.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: /welcome");
    exit;
}
    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $username = $password = "";
    $username_err = $password_err = "";

    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Check if username is empty
        if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
            $username_err = "Please enter username.";
        } else{
            $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        }

        // Check if password is empty
        if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
            $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
        } else{
            $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        }

        // Validate credentials
        if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                // Set parameters
                $param_username = $username;

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    // Store result
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                    // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                        // Bind result variables
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                                // Password is correct, so start a new session
                                session_start();

                                // Store data in session variables
                                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                                // Redirect user to welcome page
                                header("location: /welcome");
                            } else{
                                // Display an error message if password is not valid
                                $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                            }
                        }
                    } else{
                        // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                        $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }

                // Close statement
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
            .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                </div>
                <p>Don't have an account? <a href="/registration">Sign up now</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```